# How to solve the ODE $ f(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)-{f'(x)}^2=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve the differential equation $$f(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)-f'(x)^2=0$$ with $f(0) = 0 = f'(x)$.

---

my attempt:-

Let $f(x)f'(x)=z$

so we have $f'(x)^2+f(x)f''(x)= \frac{dz}{dx}$, we get

substituting in :- $ f(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)-{f'(x)}^2=0$,we get
$$f(x)f''(x)-z-\left(\frac{dz}{dx}-f(x)f''(x)\right)=0 ,$$
beyond which I'm stuck. Could someone help, please?

Comment: Better use `''` (two apostrophes) for the second derivative, not `"` (quotation mark) or `{"}`.

Comment: Will do in the future, thanks!

Comment: The initial conditions are somewhat redundant: Substituting $f(0)$ in the o.d.e. implies $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: As all the answers here are excellent, I'd prefer not to accept any answer, is that fine?

Comment: @fhhh I'd encourage you to accept some answer---say, whichever helped you most---which will help indicate to others that your question has been resolved. In general, don't worry too much about offending someone by not picking their answer: Experienced answer-writers know that question-askers can only choose one answer.

Comment: I have accepted an answer, but once again, I would like to apologise if your answer wasn't accepted, I just chose the one I connected the most with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x)f''(x)-f(x)f'(x)-{f'(x)}^2=0$$
$$\dfrac {f''(x)}{f'(x)}-1=\dfrac {f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
Integrate to reduce the order:
$$\ln (f'(x))-x=\ln f(x)+C$$
$$\ln \left (\dfrac {f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)=x+C$$
$$(\ln  f(x))'=ce^x$$
Integrate again.

Comment: Wow, it's that simple? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @fhhh

Answer (score 2):

If a non-constant solution exists and can be found symbolically, then the substitution $f'(x)=u(f(x))$ with $f''(x)=u'(f(x))u(f(x))$ often helps sort out the terms. Here it leads to
$$
fu(f)u'(f)-fu(f)-u(f)^2=0
\\
u'(f)=1+\frac{u(f)}{f}.
$$
This now is a (degree-)homogeneous ODE, with the substitution $u(f)=fv(f)$ giving
$$
fv'(f)=1\implies v(f)=a+\ln|f|, ~~ f'(x)=u(f)=af+f\ln|f|
$$
which now can be solved by setting $g=\ln|f|$, $g'(x)=a+g(x)$, ...

Comment: I see, thanks. !

Answer (score 1):

Inspection shows that constant functions are solutions and in particular that $f(x) = 0$ solves the initial value problem, but we can find the general solution to the o.d.e.

**Hint** That each term has the same number of factors $f^{(k)}(x)$ suggests substituting $$f(x) = \exp u(x) ,$$ which transforms the equation to the second-order, constant-coefficient linear o.d.e. $$u''(x) - u'(x) = 0 ,$$ which has solution $u(x) = A e^x + B$. Substituting gives
$$f(x) = e^{A e^x + B} = C e^{A e^x},$$ and allowing $C = 0$ recovers the zero solution.

Comment: thanks a lot..!